# Does Admin Privilege allow you to set your robot to any priority level?

Tags: robo-rally-2016

The upgrade card Admin Privilge says

> Once per round, you may give your robot priority for one register.

Does this mean I can make it go first, last, or anything in between?  Having admin privilege would imply I would be able to alter this setting to any level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Priority is based on proximity to the Radar Antenna ... only one robot has priority at a time, and the robot with priority is the one that moves. Admin Privileges lets you gain priority at any time, so you can go earlier in the turn, but you can not go later in the turn than when your robots priority should occur.

```
C|Spin|Zoom|Hammer
```

If C is the Antenna, and you are Zoom bot, Admin Privs would let you go before Spin bot, but not after Hammer bot.